# RXSwift eventlistener

Tags: listener, rx-swift

I´m kind of new to the reactive pattern and now I have my first bigger question.

I have done a few asychronous requests in the reactive way. But what I wan´t to do now is a "Eventlistener".

I have a `Session` object, at the moment I have an `SessionEventListener` protocol. The Session has a list of listeners and informs all of them about a successfull login and an logout. This Listeners can subscribe and unsubscribe. This thing I want to create reactive now.

How would you do that?

---

My Idea is to define a BehaviourSubject:

```
public let loginEventBehaviourSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: true)
```

now I can send onNext true if the session logged in, and false if it was logged out:

```
loginEventBehaviourSubject.onNext(true) // on login
loginEventBehaviourSubject.onNext(false) // on logout
```

And my "listeners" can subscribe to it.

But I would prefere to have subjects for every event:

```
public let loginEventBehaviourSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: )
public let logoutEventBehaviourSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: )
```

But then I wouldn´t need the bool. Can I make a kind of "empty" Subject, that only fire "events" without submitting really data.

And then my last question:
Why do I have to add an instance to the initializer of the Subject. Why can´t I create it like: `BehaviourSubject<Bool>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give an initial value to behavior subject because of it's API. Indeed, it defines `BehaviorSubject<T>.value()` method, which returns a `T`. And it would not make sense to call `value` without a proper initial value. In the presented case, I think `PublishSubject` is a better representation of the task at hand. You can find [more documentation on the available kinds of subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) on the reactivex website.

If you are only interested in the `.next` event of your subjects, you can do `let loginSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()` (using behavior subject, you could have written `BehaviorSubject<Void>(value: ())`) and will the be able to call `loginSubject.onNext()`.

---

Note though that using any subject is often an anti-pattern. Indeed, subject are most of the time intended to bridge from the imperative to the reactive world and you can very often create things like `loginEventObservable` as a combination of other observables. For more information on this, I recommend reading [To Use Subject Or Not To Use Subject?](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx). It is written using the `.Net` implementation of Rx, but the theory stays the same.